# Olingo JPA missing $batch implementation

Tags: jpa, olingo

folks:

I have followed the tutorial to implement ["Creating a Web Application Project for Transforming JPA Models into OData Services"](http://olingo.apache.org/doc/odata2/tutorials/CreateWebApp.html) . But client side complains about missing $batch implementation. Anyone can give a clue how to add $batch implementation to JPA - OData Services?

Thanks.
Jack

Comment: I have figured it out by myself. Thanks.

Comment: Want to post the answer, so as to help others in the same situation?